# How to redirect to another screen when user taps on received notification in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

In my main.dart I have this code

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await FirebaseHelper.setupFirebase();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  try {
    await NotificationsHelper.initializeNotification();
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(myBackgroundMessageHandler);
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
  } catch (e) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Then in my NotificationsHelper I have this

```
class NotificationsHelper {
  const NotificationsHelper._();

  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _notificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static const AndroidNotificationChannel _androidChannel =
      AndroidNotificationChannel(
    "high_importance_channel",
    "high_importance_channel",
    description: 'description',
    importance: Importance.max,
    playSound: true,
  );

  static NotificationDetails _notificationDetails() {
    return NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
        _androidChannel.id,
        _androidChannel.name,
        channelDescription: _androidChannel.description,
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.max,
        playSound: true,
        icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
      ),
      iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(),
    );
  }

  static Future<void> initializeNotification() async {
    AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    await _notificationsPlugin.initialize(
      InitializationSettings(
        android: androidInitializationSettings,
        iOS: const DarwinInitializationSettings(),
      ),
    );
  }

  static void onMessage(BuildContext context, RemoteMessage message) {
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    AndroidNotification? androidNotification = message.notification?.android;
    AppleNotification? appleNotification = message.notification?.apple;

    if (notification == null) return;

    if (androidNotification != null && appleNotification != null) {
      _notificationsPlugin.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        notification.title,
        notification.body,
        _notificationDetails(),
      );
    }
  }

  static void onMessageOpenedApp(BuildContext context, RemoteMessage? message) {
    RemoteNotification? notification = message?.notification;
    AndroidNotification? androidNotification = message?.notification?.android;
    AppleNotification? appleNotification = message?.notification?.apple;

    if (notification == null) return;

    if (androidNotification != null && appleNotification != null) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text(notification.title ?? "No Title"),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(notification.body ?? "No body"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

This works perfectly for me but the issue is that when user taps on the notification, it will redirect the user to initial page instead of **SecondPage(data: data);** which is where I intend to display the content of the notification in full.

Please How do I redirect the user to a specific page when he taps on the notification.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example where this is accomplished. You can pick out what you need or don't need from it for your purposes: https://github.com/hwaqar44/test-lib/blob/main/main.dart.txt

He also has a simple [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1OZFl45p3c) tutorial if you'd rather learn from that.